# Code not performing as expected [For in cycle]

Tags: python

Why is this not working? Actual result is `[]` for any entry.

```
def non_unique(ints):
    """
    Return a list consisting of only the non-unique elements from the list lst.

    You are given a non-empty list of integers (ints). You should return a
    list consisting of only the non-unique elements in this list. To do so
    you will need to remove all unique elements (elements which are
    contained in a given list only once). When solving this task, do not
    change the order of the list.

    >>> non_unique([1, 2, 3, 1, 3])
    [1, 3, 1, 3]
    >>> non_unique([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    []
    >>> non_unique([5, 5, 5, 5, 5])
    [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
    >>> non_unique([10, 9, 10, 10, 9, 8])
    [10, 9, 10, 10, 9]
    """

    new_list = []
    for x in ints:
        for a in ints:
            if ints.index(x) != ints.index(a):
                if x == a:
                    new_list.append(a)
    return new_list
```

Working code (not from me):

```
result = []
for c in ints:
  if ints.count(c) > 1:
    result.append(c)
return result
```

Comment: The conditions `ints.index(x) != ints.index(a)` and `x == a` can never be simultaneously satisfied. I don't know how you imagine they could be.

Comment: I don't know how why hey could't be. First is for index and second for value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list.index` will return the **first** index that contains the input parameter, so if `x==a` is true, then `ints.index(x)` will always equal `ints.index(a)`.  If you want to keep your same code structure, I'd recommend keeping track of the indicies within the loop using `enumerate` as in:

```
for x_ind, x in enumerate(ints):
    for a_ind, a in enumerate(ints):
        if x_ind != a_ind:
            if x == a:
                new_list.append(a)
```

Although, for what it's worth, I think your example of working code is a better way of accomplishing the same task.

Answer (score 1):

Although the example of working code is correct, if suffers from quadratic complexity which makes it slow for larger lists. I'd prefer s.th. like this:

```
from nltk.probability import FreqDist

def non_unique(ints):
    fd = FreqDist(ints)
    return [x for x in ints if fd[x] > 1]
```

It precomputes a frequency distribution in the first step, and then selects all non-unique elements. Both steps have a O(n) performance characteristic.